# How to move Facebook chat box above/below or right/left?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-chat

Facebook chat box (Customer Chat SDK) overlaps one of the buttons on my website. How I can to move it above?

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide a meaningful answer. Please consider adding some of your relevant code to your question.

Comment: It is original code

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the CSS and override to reposition, but this isn't recommended as it can possibly lead to unexpected breakage when future updates to the plugin occur.

Answer (score 0):

It is original code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>



<script>`enter code here`
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/lt_LT/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>




<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat";  
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="0000000"
  theme_color="#0084ff"
  greeting_dialog_display="hide"
>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can writing add css of website:

```
.fb_dialog, .fb_customer_chat_bounce_in_v2, .fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2 {
right: auto !important;
left: 10pt !important;
bottom: 10pt !important;}
```

In it you can change `left: 10pt !important; bottom: 10pt !important;` at your discretion.

Good Luck !